# 2 Buttons Overlapping Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

**This has been updated to be more clear due to the downvotes**

---

I am creating a window in Tkinter. This window includes:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Element  | Size               | Location          | Function Called |
|----------|--------------------|-------------------|-----------------|
| mButton1 | Width * Height     | 0, 0              | goDown()        |
| mButton2 | Width/8 * Height/8 | Width/8, Height/8 | goUp()          |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

`mButton1` works as intended and calls my function `goDown()` when clicked.

`mButton2` does not work as intended and does call do anything when clicked.

After debugging, it seems as if there are "layers" and `mButton1` is on the top layer covering `mButton2` so it can not be pressed.

My question is how can I make sure `mButton2` is on top of `mButton1` so it will call the function when clicked?

---

**Code:**

```
import tkinter, sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry("480x320") #Raspberry Pi touchscreen resolution
counter = 30

def goUp():
    counter += 1
    mButton2.config(text = "", borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', pady = "100")

def downClick():
    counter -= 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', pady = "100")

mButton1 = Button(text = counter, command = downClick, height = 4000, width = 320, font = ("Monospace", 200))
mButton1.pack()

mButton2 = Button(text = "", command = downClick, height = 50, width = 50, font = ("Monospace", 10))
mButton2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to put a little effort into learning tkinter before asking such a basic question. Most tkinter tutorials will likely cover how to do what you want.

Comment: @BryanOakley I actually tried but could not get 2 buttons to work at once.

Comment: Then show what you tried.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SWtETscs

Comment: @BryanOakley I just rewrote the question. I hope it is better! If you think it is and you want to could you please upvote it! Thanks! I already figured it out but wanted to make it better in case someone else needs help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to just make both buttons work at once, you can start with smaller size and font size.

If you want to have more command about where do your buttons appear, take a look at other  geometry managers. **Pack** is somewhat limited by nature, and it seems like it won't be enough in your case.

For buttons to overlap, you can use **Place** manager:

```
def upClick():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', pady = "100")


def downClick():
    global counter
    counter -= 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', pady = "100")

mButton1 = Button(text = counter, command = downClick, height = 4000, width = 320, font = ("Monospace", 200))
mButton1.pack()

mButton2 = Button(text = "", command = upClick, height = 5, width = 5, font = ("Monospace", 10))
mButton2.place(anchor="nw")
```

Comment: Yes, `.place(anchor="nw")` on the second button should work (but it seems like you will need to make it smaller anyway)

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to add     mButton1.config(text = counter, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0) to upClick but it works!

Comment: Updated to make things clearer for future readers.
Glad it worked :)

Comment: I just rewrote the question. I hope it is better! If you think it is and you want to could you please upvote it! Thanks! I already figured it out but wanted to make it better in case someone else needs help!